# Повторяющийся Alt и Title для изображений img

Tags: seo

Подскажите, как быть в такой ситуации. На одной странице одно за другим идут парные картинки (анимация, одно изображение черно-белое сменяется таким же но цветным), как правильно прописать для них Alt и Title, чтобы у поисковиков не было претензий, так как на изображениях нарисовано одно и тоже и описание соответственно повторяется. Вот пример кода:

```
<a href="/images/drawing/shema-razmeshhenija-kondicionerov.jpg">
    <img src="/images/drawing/shema-razmeshhenija-kondicionerov-s.jpg" title="чертеж с размещением кондиционеров и радиаторов " alt="план размещения радиаторов и кондиционеров в жилом помещении">
    <img class="blackDraw" src="/images/drawing/black/shema-razmeshhenija-kondicionerov-b.jpg" title="" alt="">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Для чёрно-белого изображения: "*план с размещением кондиционеров и
  радиаторов (чёрно-белый)*" и "*чёрно-белый план размещения радиаторов и
  кондиционеров в жилом помещении*".
- Соответственно, для цветного изображения: "*план с размещением кондиционеров и
  радиаторов (цветной)*" и "*цветной план размещения радиаторов и кондиционеров в 
  жилом помещении*".

Или же что-то подобноею Обратите внимание, что я позволил себе заменить в титле ваше слово "чертёж" на слово "план", т.к. это различные слова с различной семантикой. Разумеется, вы можете оставить всё как есть, или же, наоборот, изменить слово "план" на слово "чертёж". Также вы можете изменять содержание титла и альта. Мои рекомендации не есть правило. Общее правило - это для различных изображений - различные титлы и алты. *Определите самостоятельно **ключевое различие и отобразите это в содержании этих тэгов/элементов***.